# C++ concurrency vector search

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a big vector of orders and want todo a search to return all orders that fall within a given date. The vector is already sorted.

Using a for loop with linear search take very long.

Maybe can use a binary search of using concurrency to search the vector.

Comment: `std::equal_range`? And it doesn't have a parallel version.

Comment: Using a binary search (in a single thread) will already drop you from linear time to logarithmic. I wouldn't go into using multiple threads unless you really need it (which you'll know only after profiling).

Comment: You could do the two binary searches in parallel but I'd doubt it'll improve performance by much.